'No Configuration available' error with springboot+freemarker
I am writing a unit test for a service in my spring boot app. Service uses a dependency(HtmlGenerator) that makes use of freemarker API.
I try to set this in the test as:
FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates");
freeMarkerConfigurer.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8"); 
HtmlGenerator htmlGenerator = new HtmlGenerator(freeMarkerConfigurer);
service.setHtmlGenerator(htmlGenerator);

In service when I try to call a method on HtmlGenerator, I get an error related to freemarker configuration:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Configuration available

at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer.getConfiguration(FreeMarkerConfigurer.java:140)

Seems it is not able to load some configuration it needs.
What am I missing in my setup?
Edit:
Spring boot version is 2.0.4
mockito is 2.22.0
I am using following annotation on my test:
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)


How should we answer without having an overview. Spring Boot already configures Freemarker so reuse that instead of re-creating your own. Your test is not using Spring but plain Mockito, so not sure how and what you are testing with just those lines of code.
